# Java Input not working (Beginner)

Tags: java, input, system

For some reason, my code will not accept input on the last line "What would you like to order: "

Could anyone tell me what my error is here? It is compiling correctly and everything. I am only a beginner so please tell me in basic terms.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

class RestaurantMain {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        //Create an array list
        ArrayList menu = new ArrayList();

        //Variables//
        int choice;
        int customerChoice;
        boolean trueFalse;
        int restart = 0;
        String choice2;
        String addItems = "";
        int menuCount = 0;
        int indexCount = 0;
        String item = "";

        //Import input device
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList theMenu = new ArrayList();

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Cooper's restaurant system!");
        System.out.println("How can I help?");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("1. Customer System");
        System.out.println("2. Management System");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Which option do you choose: ");
        choice = in.nextInt();

            if (choice == 1) {
                System.out.println("Our menu's are as follows:");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("1. Drinks");
                System.out.println("2. Starters");
                System.out.println("3. Mains");
                System.out.println("4. Desserts");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Please note - You MUST order 5 items.");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.print("What menu would you like to follow? ");
                customerChoice = in.nextInt();

                    if (customerChoice == 1) {
                        System.out.println("Drinks Menu");
                            System.out.println("Would you like to order? ");
                            choice2 = in.nextLine();
                                if (choice2 == "yes") {
                                    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of items you want to order: ");
                                    while (indexCount <= menuCount);
                                        System.out.println("Please enter your item: ");
                                        item = in.nextLine(); {
                                        theMenu.add(item);
                                    }
                                    }

                    }
                    if (customerChoice == 2) {
                        System.out.println("Starters Menu");
                    }
                    if (customerChoice == 3) {
                        System.out.println("Mains menu");
                    }
                    if (customerChoice == 4) {
                        System.out.println("Desserts Menu");
                    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the only issue, but you're trying to use == to compare strings. Use .equals() instead.

Comment: Even more, use `"yes".equals(choice2)` instead of `choice2.equals("yes")`. It's a good practice which save you from wild `NullPointerException` :)

Comment: Thanks guys! Hope you both have a good day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `in.nextLine()` right after the line where you call `in.nextInt()`
The reason is that just asking for the next integer doesn't consume the entire line from the input, and so you need skip ahead to the next new-line character in the input by calling `in.nextLine()`

```
customerChoice = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine();
```

This pretty much has to be done each time you need to get a new line after calling a method that doesn't consume the entire line. Consider using a `BufferedReader` object instead!

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int integer = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
```

This will throw the same errors that `Scanner.nextInt()` does if the input can't be parsed as an integer.

Regarding your comment about errors, there is one:

```
while (indexCount <= menuCount);
System.out.println("Please enter your item: ");
item = in.nextLine(); {
 theMenu.add(item);
}
```

}

Should instead be like the following:

```
while(indexCount <= menuCount){
    System.out.println("Please enter your item: ");
    item = in.nextLine();
    theMenu.add(item);
}
```

Also, it isn't strictly necessary, but I suggest that you do declare the ArrayList's generic type when instantiating the list, so that further calls to theMenu.get() don't need to be casted to a String.

```
ArrayList<String> theMenu = new ArrayList<String>();
```

When comparing strings, ensure that you use the `str.equals("string to compare with")` method, instead of the equality operator (`==`). Therefore for example, `choice2 == "yes"` should instead be `choice2.equals("yes")`. Using `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals` would ignore case differences, which may be useful in this situation.

Comment: Also can I ask, do you see any beginner errors in my code that I cane improve upon? Many thanks! Have a good day!

Comment: There is one error, see my edited answer for info! @CoopersInc

Comment: I can't thank you enough @SamTebbs33! Your information is greatly appreciated and will go well towards my final exam + management system :) Reading through this will help a lot when needed. Is there any way to repay a favour?

Answer (score 2):

insted of  in.nextLine(); function you just try another scanner functions like 'in.next()'. just R&D with the methods that already give the JVM itself.
you just use correct the logic and use equal() or  equlIgnoreCase() methods insted of "=" operator.