# Two methods executing at the same time? Why?

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement, execution

```
package contractmanager;
import java.util.*;
/**
*
* @author Tom McCloud
*/
public class ContractManager {
    static Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
    // global scanner
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int option;
        //variable declaration
        String clientName;
        String packageSize;
        String dataBundle;
        String reference;
        int period;
        boolean intlCalls;
        //display menu to user
        System.out.println("Welcome: \n");
        System.out.println("1. Enter new contract       ");
        System.out.println("2. Display contract summary");
        System.out.println("3. Display summary of contract for selected month");
        System.out.println("4. Find and display contract");
        System.out.println("0. Exit");

        //take option off user
        option = keyb.nextInt();

        //WIP - only working on option 1 at the minute
        switch(option) {
        case 1:
               clientName = clientName();
               packageSize = packageSize();
               dataBundle = dataBundle();
               reference = reference();
               break;
        }

        exit();

    }

    public static void exit()
    {
        System.out.println("Thank you for using the contract manager. Goodbye!");
    }

    public static String clientName()
    {
        String name = " ";
        System.out.println("Please input your full name: ");
        name = keyb.nextLine(); 


         return name;
    }

    public static String packageSize()
    {
        String size;

        System.out.println("Please input your package size: ");
        System.out.println(" 1. Small \n 2. Medium \n 3. Large");
        size = keyb.next();

        return size; 
    }

    public static String dataBundle()
    {
        String data;

            System.out.println("Please input data bundle size: ");
            System.out.println("1. Low \n 2. Medium \n 3. High \n 4. Unlimited");
            data = keyb.next();


        return data;
    }

    public static String reference()
    {
        String ref;
        boolean isRefValid = false;
        do {
            System.out.println("Please input your reference code: ");
            ref = keyb.next();

            if(ref.length() > 6)
            {
                System.out.println("Reference number too long, re-enter!");
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
               if(Character.isDigit(ref.charAt(i)))
               {
                   System.out.println("First two characters must be letters!");
               }
            }

        } while(isRefValid = false);

        return ref;     
    }
}
```

So, this is some code I have. If I press `enter code here`one, it executes these, now technically shouldn't this be in order of one another once each method reaches completion and returns?

For example, on execution after pressing "1" I get the following output:

```
Please input your full name: 
Please input your package size: 
 1. Small 
 2. Medium 
 3. Large
```

Whereas this should come one by one, after the full name has been inputted it should move onto the package size step. If I input it goes to the third step rather than repeating for the second step's input.

Comment: technically speacking, yes it should, practical speacking, no clue, since the code you provided doesn´t give us enough information.

Comment: Please provide the other cases. so that we can help you

Comment: give me your full code

Comment: Please provide a *[Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)*. The code you have provided cannot be run by somebody else to produce the behaviour you report.

Comment: I can see this being a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29238680/java-input-not-working-beginner/29238741#29238741

Comment: Added full code. Sorry, first question here.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because in your `clientName` function you have just printed "Please input your full name: " without waiting for input. For example you have to do something like below here scan.nextLine() will wait until user have press enter:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner();
System.out.println("Please input your full name:");

String name= scan.next();

System.out.println(name);

scan.nextLine();
```

Updated: Try by updating clientName function as below

```
public static String clientName() {
    String name = " ";
    System.out.println("Please input your full name: ");
    name = keyb.next();

    keyb.nextLine();

    return name;
}
```

Comment: If you look at my code, you're right, taking 
`nextLine();` and replacing with `next();` works for the first function, but after the first input, it loads function 2 and 3 at the same time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works. Am I right in understanding that this is because next() will take everything until the space key is pressed? 

If so, why does that then load two functions?